# Trouble with Civicron.php

Tags: cron-job

Trying to run civicron though cli and it was working fine till a week or so ago when now it seems to hang and nothing happens.  Have tried trouble shooting with no luck any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry about lack of facts. I am on CIVICRM 5.1.1 and WP 5.1.1 the command line that is running is

/usr/local/bin/php /home/sitedirector/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s mysite.com -u XXXXX -p XXXXXXXXX -e job -a execute

This was working fine however now it just hangs and takes up the CPU, Same if I run it in the console and not by CRON.

Comment: You should also check the log files. CiviCRM has a log file and I dont know the location of that file in wordpress. But in Drupal it is under sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog Maybe there is an error in the log which explains why the cron is hanging.

Comment: Nothing is written to the log files have checked several times.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing much background information. However, the following question/answer may be related:
[Failed loading "ioncube_loader_lin_7.2.so" Cron Error after CiviCRM & WordPress Upgrades](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28839/failed-loading-ioncube-loader-lin-7-2-so-cron-error-after-civicrm-wordpress)

In short: There was a mismatch of php versions after an upgrade. Probably, a good starting point for you would be to check, if there have been any recent system upgrades.

In general, it would be helpful to state your civi version, the type and version of cms you are using, the command line you are trying to run plus any related messages and possibly any changes before the problem occured.